# AttributeError: 'sphere' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python

Возникла такая ошибка, я не могу понять, как определить атрибут x. Помогите, пожалуйста. (Результат задания: сфера должна отскакивать от стены).

```
from vpython import*
ball = sphere(pos=vector(-5,0,0), radius=0.5, color=color.red)
wallR = box(pos=vector(6,0,0), sixe=(0.2,4,4), color=color.green)
dt=0.05
ball.velocity = vector(2,0,0)
while(1==1):
    rate(100)
    ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.velocity*dt
    if ball.x > wallR.y:
        ball.velocity.x= -ball.velocity.x
```

Answer (score 2):

Замените `ball.x` на `ball.pos.x`.